# Mean values of this 3-D array along the third dimension in java

Tags: java, matlab, math, matrix

How do I compute the mean of a 3-D matrix which is similar to using **mean(array, 3)** in matlab, where 'array' is 3-D ie. mean values of a 3-D array along the third dimension. A java equivalent

Answer (score 0):

For each element in the 3rd dimension you get a 2D matrix. For instance,

```
int my3darray[][][] = new int[10][20][30];
new2darray = my3darray[i];
```

For that 2D matrix you can calculate the mean value. For instance,

The size of a 2D array can be calculated as follows:

```
array.length * array[0].length;
```

Then more or less this is what you need:

```
int rows = 2;   // you get the size from array.length 
int cols = 3;   // you get the size from array[0].length
int i, j;
for (i=0;i<rows;i++); {
    for (i=0;j<cols;j++); {
        sum += res[i][j];
    }
}
System.out.println(sum/(rows*cols))
```

In case you are using [Apache Common Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html) there is a `getMean` and a `mean` function and you can use it like this:

```
// assume values is a double[] array
double mean = StatUtils.mean(values);
```

Comment: Nope, mean(rand(4,5,6),3) would only average on the third dimension, so the result would be a matrix of size (4,5) and each element of the result would be such that result(i,j) = mean( squeeze( original(i,j,:) ) )

Comment: Yes! @aka.nice That's exact what I want to compute using java.